# In .NET Core when I am passing date less then SQL Server min date to WCF with entity service accept it and Entity Framework Core fails

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am passing `Fromdate = 28-09-0001 00:00:00` and `ToDate = 29-09-0001 00:00:00`.

I have 2 services - one with WCF with Entity Framework: in this, I get back a success response - but with the same scenario, when I test with .NET Core + Entity Framework Core, the call fails.

I get an error

> SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

Comment: Do you use the exact same database ? Because SQL Server `DateTime` type does not support dates from before the 01/01/1753. For that you need to use `datetime2` : [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Have you tried to debug and check value passed to Entity framework? Because the error looks like from Database, as you use the same database it means, that somewhere in WCF scenario DateTime.MinValue might be inserted. Please provide example, or locate place with error more precionally.

Comment: Maybe the WCF translates to SqlDateTime.MinValue